# Failed on Start : SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflows failed on start

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created 3 SharePoint 2010 workflows before several months.Those were working fine till now.

But suddenly before a week it is getting failed. I haven't published any newer newer version for several months.

**PS:I am using SharePoint Online.**

It shows **Status:"Failed on Start"** and below errors in workflow history list:

[image: Error Description]

Comment: Any updates on this? Patch for Sharepoint available yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an update recently that (might) caused some issues with workflows.

This is not a SharePoint update, but it affects SHarePoint.

Check if you have any of these KB's installed:

KB4457915: Security Only Update for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2 for Windows Embedded 8 Standard and Windows Server 2012

KB4457919: Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2 for Windows Embedded 8 Standard and Windows Server 2012

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/

Note
Microsoft is aware of this issue and patches for SharePoint 2010, 2013 and 2016 are being worked as of 9/17/2018. I will update when we have an ETA. I had confirmation from the product team on 9/18/2018 that this information and solution on this post is in the line with the future patch and it is the recommended action plan until the patch is out. If anything change, I will update the post.

Comment: I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 and SharePoint Online. and I have published workflows before 4-5 months. since then I haven't changed anything. So does it matter to me ?

Comment: SPO have mitigated the problem, and it should not happen to you anymore. Not sure if your farm is fixed yet though. (Aka: give it a day...)